# How do I join the values of two columns in a Pandas dataframe only if none are NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, notnull

I'm trying to join two string in a new column within a DataFrame, but have tried several approaches and none work, the closest I have come is with a lambda formula, but still can't understand the problem. Can anyone help?

Data frame:

```
    full_name   certificacion   company
member_#            
296057  John Doe    A          CO3
155977  Jane Doe    NaN        CO2
228610  Johnny Doe  A, C       CO3
```

and I need a new column that has 'full_name' and 'certification' as:

```
member_name
John Doe, A
Jane Doe
Johnny Doe, A, C
```

I am trying:

```
df['member_name'] = df[df.columns[['full_name', 'certificacion']]].apply(
    lambda x: ', '.join() if x['certificacion'].notnull() else x['full_name'], axis=1)
```

But get an error:

> IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`),
> numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

I am new at Pandas and have tried several variations of the above lambdas function but I can't seem to find the right syntax.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since both columns are strings, you can add them together with a `+` with `,`  between. Then for the rows that have `NaN` just handle those with `np.where()` logic to use `full_name` instead of `member_name`:

```
df['member_name'] = df['full_name'] + ', ' + df['certificacion']
df['member_name'] = np.where((df['member_name'].isna()), df['full_name'], df['member_name'])
```

output:

```
member_#      full_name certificacion company       member_name
0    296057    John Doe             A     CO3       John Doe, A
1    155977    Jane Doe           NaN     CO2          Jane Doe
2    228610  Johnny Doe          A, C     CO3  Johnny Doe, A, C
```

Comment: Oneliner: `df["full_name"].where(df["certificacion"].isnull(), df["full_name"]+", "+df["certificacion"])`.

Answer (score 0):

Another one liner

```
df['member_name']=np.where(df['Certificacion'].isna(), df['full_name'], df['full_name']+', '+df['Certificacion'])
```